# calling php variables not working

Tags: php, mysql

Everything in this program works except when I try to insert a variable to my database. Instead of transfering the variables($q, $w, $e) to the database, the process fails. Please note that if I change the variables into integers or strings the process succeeds. Could you please help me? THX

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $w = $_POST['w'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    // bring variables from browser works
    $con=mysql_connect("mysql5.000webhost.com","*****","*****","*****");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    // connection to server works

    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `a5637490_test`.`test` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES ($q, 14, $w, $e)');
    mysql_close($con);

    echo 'success';

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string variables are not properly escaped. You need to quote them like

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO a5637490_test.test (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES ('$q', 14, '$w', '$e')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO a5637490_test.test (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES ('$q', 14, '$w', '$e')");
```

**Note that:** `mysql_` extensions are deprecated, and your code this way is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or prepared statements instead.

Comment: I think there is a small typing mistake here, the quotes around insert statement in above case would be double ones or its a parse error

Comment: It will give you syntax error

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ - Sorry, I copied it from the OP question. Updated now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO a5637490_test.test (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES ($q, 14, $w, $e)");
```

You have to use double quotes.  Single quotes doesn't allow injection of variables directly in the string.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO a5637490_test.test (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES ('".$q."', 14, '".$w."', '".$e."')"); mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***double quotes***

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO a5637490_test.test (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES ($q, 14, $w, $e)");
```